# How to generate PDF from XML message

Tags: wso2-esb

What is the best practice to generate PDF out of the current message.

I'm thinking about using xsl-fo but I didn't find any components for that.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a custom mediator

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Sample+380%3A+Writing+your+own+Custom+Mediation+in+Java

You can see here an example

https://github.com/Mystes/wso2-esb-pdf-mediator/blob/master/README.md